# Connection Failiure when trying to upload an image file

Tags: android, http, url-routing

I am trying to upload an image by converting it to a string buffer to a server. But I always get the mentioned error exception when connecting.

isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Above is the exception I am getting

This is the code I have used to upload image

```
jsonSendData = new JSONObject();
jsonSendData.put("data", sendData);

URL url = new URL(getFieldTCTEnableStr("URL"));
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    //method
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    //header
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(jsonSendData.toString());
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Try disabling the proxy on both

Comment: can you add your image uploading code?

Comment: I have added the relevant code. Thank you

Comment: How can I disable proxy in android device??